# Json Parse Unexpected token with node

Tags: json, node.js, powershell

I am getting a strange unexpected token error trying to parse a JSON file using node.  I have tested the code with 2 files that look identical.  I used a code compare tool to do a comparison and they do appear identical.  However, when I try to parse them, one gets the error and the other does not.  The file that does not work is being generated from a PowerShell script.  The one that does work was manually created.  I am baffled.  One thing I noticed that is different about them when I write the json out to the console is, the one that does not work has a ? at the beginning.

The json from the file that does not work:

data = ?{    "stack_name":  "perf-a",    "parameters":  {                       "StackSet":  "b",                       "MonitoringEnableAutoscalingAlarm":  "True",                       "MachineConfigEnvironment":  "Perf",                       "AppEnvironmentType":  "perf",                       "StackInRotation":  "True",                       "MonitoringEnableNotificationOnlyAlarms":  "False",                       "AMIImage":  "ami-123456789"                   },    "tags":  {                 "CostCenter":  "12345",                 "Owner":  "test@test.com"             },    "cft_file":
"cft/cft.json"}

The json from the file that does work:

data = {    "stack_name":  "perf-a",    "parameters":  {                       "StackSet":  "a",                       "MonitoringEnableAutoscalingAlarm":  "True",                       "MachineConfigEnvironment":  "Perf",                       "AppEnvironmentType":  "perf",                       "StackInRotation":  "True",                       "MonitoringEnableNotificationOnlyAlarms":  "False",                       "AMIImage":  "ami-123456789"                   },    "tags":  {                 "CostCenter":  "45229",                 "Owner":  "test@test.com"             },    "cft_file":  "
cft/cft.json"}

The code I am using for testing is:

```
var envFile = "perf2.json";
var fs = require('fs');
console.log('envFile = ' + envFile);
fs.readFile(envFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log('error reading variables file');
    throw err;
}
try {

    var JsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('JsonData = ' + JsonData);
    data = data.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
           .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
           .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
           .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
           .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
           .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
           .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
           .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f")
           .replace(/\\0/g, "")
           .replace(/\\v/g, "")
           .replace(/\\e/g, "\\e");
    data = data.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g, "");
    console.log('data = ' + data);
    var cftVariables = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('cftVariables = ' + cftVariables);
    console.log('cftVariables stack name = ' + cftVariables.stack_name);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error parsing variables file');
    throw e;
}

});
```

As you can see, I have also tried JSON.stringify but I lose the properties and cftVariables.stack_name becomes undefined.

This problem has been plaguing me for several days and I am now at a loss as to how to fix it.

For reference, here is the snippet of PowerShell that creates the file.  The problem might be there.

```
$savePath = "envs/" +$filetouse + ".json"

            $parameters = @{AppEnvironmentType =$AppEnvironmentType;
                  StackSet = $StackSet;
                  StackInRotation = $StackInRotation;
                  AMIImage = $amiid;
                  MonitoringEnableAutoscalingAlarm = $MonitoringEnableAutoscalingAlarm;
                  MonitoringEnableNotificationOnlyAlarms= $MonitoringEnableNotificationOnlyAlarms;
                  MachineConfigEnvironment = $MachineConfigEnvironment;
                  }
            $tags = @{Owner = "test@test.com";
                    CostCenter = "45229";
                    }

            $envcft = @{stack_name =$stack_name;
                    cft_file = "cft/cft.json";
                    parameters = $parameters;
                    tags = $tags;
                    } | ConvertTo-Json 
            Write-host("Saving the env file with the new amiId... ")

            $envcft | Out-File $savePath -Encoding UTF8 -force
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `?` at the beginning?  That isn't valid json normally....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading the data in from a file, once you have the string you can use the remove function to get rid of that "?".

Something like this:

```
s = s.replace('?','');
```

> EDIT

since the replace did not work, try 1) either not specifying an encoding when you save the file, or 2) specify UTF16

Comment: I tried that.  It didn't actually remove it.  It's almost like that ? Is actually part of the string.  It's driving me nuts

Comment: The `?` might actually be a character that your console font doesn't have an encoding for.  Your best bet might be to edit the file, and then fix the generator to use only US-ASCII or UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I suspect you may be correct, or the "?" is a BOM which is why I suggest not specifying the encoding when the file is written from the powershell script. Would you concur?

Comment: I was specifying the encode as UTF8 in the powershell script.  I switched to ascii and that seems to have fixed the issue in my test code.  Now I will try it with my actual code.

Comment: @PaulStoner yeah, BOM sounds about right (`0xfeff` for UTF-16le IIRC).  Generally, I've found that the auto-grokking of encoding formats in programming languages to be pretty weak, so best to ensure the output and match the input encoding to that, unless you can't control the generator -- in which case you might need to do your own sniffing and dynamic encoding setup.

Comment: This has been maddening.  If I opened the file and then just did a "save as", the file was fine.  But seeing as this is all supposed to be part of an automated process to update our AWS environments, that isn't an viable option. LOL

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rhonda Sounds like you need to do what I suggested, and read the first few bytes (in binary - not characters in text) of the file and sniff out the BOM yourself, then set the encoding manually.  Here's a useful link to map the BOM to an encoding format.  Good luck!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @PaulProgrammer  switching to Ascii instead of utf-8 worked.